# ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError in content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, serialization

I have my User model with the following functions:

```
def self.chart_data(start = 1.weeks.ago)
  total_users = users_by_day(start)
  (start.to_date..Date.today).map do |date|
    {
      created_at: date,
      users: total_users[date] || 0
    }
  end
end

def self.users_by_day(start)
  users = where(created_at: start.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now)
  users = users.group("date(created_at), id")
  users = users.select("created_at, count(id) as total_users")
  users.each_with_object({}) do |user, total_users|
    total_users[user.created_at.to_date] = total_users
  end
end
```

And my View has the following line:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", id: "users_chart", data: {users: User.chart_data} %>
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError in Static#statistics

Showing statistics.html.erb where line #5 raised:

object references itself
```

When i i just print the data it looks as the following:

```
[{:created_at=>Wed, 27 Nov 2013, :users=>0}, {:created_at=>Thu, 28 Nov 2013, :users=>0}, {:created_at=>Fri, 29 Nov 2013, :users=>0}, {:created_at=>Sat, 30 Nov 2013, :users=>0}, {:created_at=>Sun, 01 Dec 2013, :users=>0}, {:created_at=>Mon, 02 Dec 2013, :users=>0}, {:created_at=>Tue, 03 Dec 2013, :users=>{Tue, 03 Dec 2013=>{...}}}, {:created_at=>Wed, 04 Dec 2013, :users=>0}]
```

The only user is on 03 Dec, if there are no users there is also no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you'll note in the printed data, there is a recursive reference on the 3rd:

```
{:created_at=>Tue, 03 Dec 2013, :users=>{Tue, 03 Dec 2013=>{...}}}
```

The origins come from how `users_by_day` is constructed. The has building references itself, by assigning an object on a given day to itself:

```
users.each_with_object({}) do |user, total_users|
  total_users[user.created_at.to_date] = total_users
end
```

I think this is just an oversight in variable naming. The aggregate object you are creating is called `total_users` by the block, and it's the same name you give it inside the query. I believe the correct block would be this:

```
 users.each_with_object({}) do |user, total_users|
   total_users[user.created_at.to_date] = user.total_users
 end
```

Since you need to get the total off the user variable.